# Absolute beginner in F# - help required

Tags: string, f#

I have the following piece of code -

```
let items = [
    (20,"cat");
    (13,"can");
    (19,"letter");
    (55,"dog");
    (87,"kettle");
    (122,"weight");
]
```

Can someone show me an example that will give the name of the item with number 13?
Everything I try returns an error, looked online for some examples but none are out there!

NOTE - Previous solution not working. What is the simplest way to carry out this operation?

Comment: Post what you tried, and the error you got. We'll be able to help then.

Comment: @ppeterka Also getting this error

easy.fs(38,37): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    string    
but here has type
    char

Comment: 'a' is a char, "a" is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let getName people id =
    people 
    |> Seq.filter (fun person -> fst person = id)
    |> Seq.head
    |> snd

    // or: |> Seq.filter (fst >> (=) id)

let getId people name =
    people 
    |> Seq.filter (fun person -> snd person = name)
    |> Seq.head
    |> fst

let getNames people =
    people
    |> List.map snd
```

You can call these as follows:

```
printfn "%d" (getId people "LIAM")
printfn "%s" (getName people 44567)
printfn "%A" (getNames people)
```

Comment: Thanks very much Patrick for your help. This works great for me. I will experiment with manipulating different lists for a while but will probably end up back on here again asking for help!
Thanks again

Comment: Use Seq.find instead of Seq.filter ... |> Seq.head